# BeautifulSoup: search into the .text attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following situation

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<span class='generic'><span>Hey</span><span>Joe</span></span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tag = soup.find('span', text="HeyJoe")
print(tag)
```

Which prints `None`.

But If I run

`soup.find('span', text="Hey").parent.text`

it returns `HeyJoe`, so it returns the "full" text including the children's text. I believed the `text=` parameter of the `find()` function would also search into the "full" text., that is, into the `.text` tag.

I have to find the parent `span` tag (the one with the class `generic`).

I would like to do it by invoking a BeautifulSoup function that search into the `.text` element. So that it would concatenate the text in all the children tags before searching. Is there such a function?

1. I cannot use the class to find the tag, because in the real-case it is a very generic class widely used by a lot of tags
2. I would like not to search for the children `span` with the `Hey` text, and then retrieve the parent, since also this is pretty generic in the real case.

Is there no way to search into the `.text` attribute of an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use below to find `span` node by complete text content `"HeyJoe"`:

```
tag = [span for span in soup.findAll('span') if span.text == "HeyJoe"][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your wording, it isn't at all clear what you're trying to do.

If you would like to search for a specific pattern, you can use `re.compile` and pass it directly to BeautifulSoup's `text=` keyword argument, e.g.

```
soup.find("span", text=re.compile("Hey"))
```

This will return for the first instance of the string "Hey" in any span tag on the page, if any. If you would like case-insensitivity, use:

```
soup.find("span", text=re.compile("Hey", re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: I want to find a selenium WebElement that matches a certain characteristic for the `.text` attribute. For example, find all the `<span>` elements which `.text` attribute equals `Hi there`.

Comment: You accepted a different answer 2 days ago but left this comment 3 hours ago. The accepted answer does what you say you want. Why leave this comment?